# Where can one find the accelerations due to high-order terms of the geopotential model?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, astrodynamics

The expression for the orbital perturbation due to J2 ($\mathbf{a_{J2}} = [a_r \ a_s \ a_w]^T$) as well as its derived effect on the argument of perigee and the right ascension of the ascending node are well known and available in most books.

Regarding higher-order terms related to the zonal harmonics or oblateness ($J_3, J_4, ...$) and multipole perturbations ($J_{22}, J_{3m}, J_{4m}, ...$), usually the general equation of the potential $V(r,\delta,\lambda)$ is provided, since it is an infinite series anyway.

Is there any reliable source where the derived perturbations $\mathbf{a_{J_{nm}}} = [a_r \ a_s \ a_w]^T$ for the cases that consider up to J3, J4, etc. are presented? I am looking into preparing a propagator that numerically integrates the osculating orbital elements affected by these perturbations, and I wonder if these expressions are already available somewhere.

Comment: related but different quetions: [Ceres gravity from spherical harmonics from Dawn, how to get the coefficients, definitions and potential?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27689/12102) and [How can I verify my reconstructed gravity field of Ceres from spherical harmonics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27779/12102)

Answer (score 6):

In Vallado's *Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications*, Section 8.6.1: Gravity Field of a Central Body, he derives the equations to calculate perturbations due to aspherical bodies. In Section 8.7.1: Application: Simplified Acceleration Model, he walks through an example calculating the acceleration due to J2 through J6 (as well as from atmospheric drag) and provides the explicit equations. In Appendix D.1: Gravitational Coefficients, he provides values of some of the coefficients from the EGM-08 model.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this announcement from the JPL mail list `ssd-announce@list.jpl.nasa.gov`:

> During the week of April 12, the Horizons ephemeris system will be updated to replace the DE430/431 planetary ephemeris, used since 2013, with the new DE440/441 solution and sixteen most massive small-body perturbers.
>
> The new DE440/441 general-purpose planetary solution includes seven additional years of ground and space-based astrometric data, data calibrations, and dynamical model improvements, most significantly involving Jupiter, Saturn, Pluto, and the Kuiper Belt.
>
> **For details, see "The JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE440 and DE441", R.S. Park, et al., The Astronomical Journal, 161:105 (15pp), 2021 March.**

That paper is [The JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE440 and DE441](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/abd414/meta) but it may be paywalled.

See

> 3.2. Point-mass Interaction with Extended Bodies

Equation 28 and all the accompanying material together forms a self-consistent basis. It is too long and I am too error prone for it to be advisable for me to reproduce everything here.

The pair of [Development Ephemerides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris) that these are replacing is discussed in [The Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE430 and DE431](ftp://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/planets/de430_and_de431.pdf) which does not appear to be paywalled and looks to be very similar (which is not a surprise).

> III.B. Point Mass Interaction with Extended Bodies